# Create lookup item with workflow

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

I have to create an item at the end of my workflow.
The list that will contain the item has a lookup column...
So I'm using the option : "Create item" and setting the values one by one.
But how can I set the value for the lookup column with the workflow current item link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question right.
If you need a current item url from the workflow, you need to open a dialog box for a value (button fx) and select:

*Data source: **Workflow Context** 
 
Field from source: **Current Item URL***

as in the example below:
 [image]

Although, if you need to add this as a lookup column (providing the current url is a lookup value in another list), then you need to: 
1. Create a calculated field with type of "Single line of text", in your lookup list and set the formula to:
*=[Your Lookup Field]*
2. In the bottom dialog from the example, select:
*DataSource: **Your Lookup List**

Field from source: **Your lookup field name***

Find the List Item
*Field: **Your calculated field name**

Value: **fx***

Lookup for Single line of text
*Data source: **Workflow Context**

Field from source: **Current Item Url***

as in the example below (calculated field name: StringLookupValue):
[image]

Comment: Using this way, the data will contain the url ... is it possible to display the item name and make it contain the url instead?

Comment: It depends where you want to display this item. You can for example create a string workflow variable and set its value to: "WorkflowContext:CurrentItemUrl, CurrentItem:Title". That creates a url with a title (format: URL, TITLE). Then use the variable where you need.

Comment: yep it's ok i found the solution...
the lookup field is based of a sharepoint list...
In the workflow i can set the vaue of currentitem:ID
lookup works with ID value :)